# XSD to java beans

Tags: java, xml, xsd, javabeans, xjc

I am new to XSDs format. I am trying to convert one xsd to java bean using xjc.But on converting I am getting multiple beans rather than getting just one bean.How to obtain one single bean from the XSD?

Below is my xsd.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xs:element name="TradeMessage" type="TradeMessageType"/>
        <xs:simpleType name="empty-string">
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="" />
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:simpleType name="decimal-or-empty">
            <xs:union memberTypes="xs:decimal empty-string" />
        </xs:simpleType>
        <xs:complexType name="contractingEntityType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="tradingAccountType" name="tradingAccount"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="executingEntityType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="tradingAccountType" name="tradingAccount"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="tradeFeesType">
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:element type="tradeFees_itemType" name="tradeFees_item"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="settlementCurrencyType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="iSOCode"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="tradingAccountType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="uniqueID"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="currencyType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="iSOCode"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="tradingInstrumentType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="CUSIP"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="tradeFees_itemType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="chargeCodeType" name="chargeCode"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="inConsideration"/>
                <xs:element type="currencyType" name="currency"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="currencyValue"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="IncomingTradeMessageType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="IncomingTradeType" name="IncomingTrade"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="TradeMessageType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="IncomingTradeMessageType" name="IncomingTradeMessage"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="schemaVersion"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="chargeCodeType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="theirTradingAccountType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="uniqueID"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="organisationUniqueID"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="tradeCurrencyType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="iSOCode"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="transactionTypeType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="uniqueID"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="channelType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="IncomingTradeType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="blockTradeReference"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="sourceReference"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="sourceVersion"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="nominal"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="price"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tradeDate"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="valueDate"/>
                <xs:element type="transactionTypeType" name="transactionType"/>
                <xs:element type="tradingInstrumentType" name="tradingInstrument"/>
                <xs:element type="tradeCurrencyType" name="tradeCurrency"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="cancelled"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="tradeTime"/>
                <xs:element type="tradeFeesType" name="tradeFees"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="grossConsideration"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="netConsideration"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:decimal" name="settlementConsideration"/>
                <xs:element type="settlementCurrencyType" name="settlementCurrency"/>
                <xs:element type="decimal-or-empty" name="settlementExRate"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="settlementExRateDirection"/>
                <xs:element type="theirTradingAccountType" name="theirTradingAccount"/>
                <xs:element type="executingEntityType" name="executingEntity"/>
                <xs:element type="contractingEntityType" name="contractingEntity"/>
                <xs:element type="decimal-or-empty" name="calculatedNetPrice"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="dealingCapacity"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="agreedPriceIndicator"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="orderReference"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="lastAmendedOnBusinessDate"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="creationAsatDate"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bpsBranchAccountNumber"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bpsAccountType"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="shortSell"/>
                <xs:element type="decimal-or-empty" name="facilitationPercentage"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="isStepOut"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="stepOutBrokerMPID"/>
                <xs:element type="xs:string" name="bargainConditionFO"/>
                <xs:element type="channelType" name="channel"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

This XSD is giving me different beans for different properties but actually I would need just one bean comprising of all the properties. As per my requirement I would receive input message (as per above xsd) and convert it directly to java bean and use this bean for further processing. If there is some other better strategy ,kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This is how JAXB works. A complex schema type is mapped to a Java class, and since this schema has many complex types you get several Java classes. When unmarshalling an XML document, you'll get one `TradeMessageType` instance.